# Auto hide scrolling content sidebar on touch devices

Tags: css

So, my problem is that when I have some scrolled element, scrollbar on touch/mobile devices doesn't hide automatically when I didn't scroll the content. It's always stays visible. But, I have to say, I don't know if it's problem with my CSS `.touch .scrollable` rules or it's because I'm testing this in device emulator in Chrome (I don't have with me right now actual mobile device on which I could test it). If someone can take a look at my code: http://jsfiddle.net/om4xmwnh/ and tell if/what is wrong with it I would really appreciate the help. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

by using css we cannot Auto hide scrolling content sidebar on touch devices

we have to use mordernize js

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but if you want to hide the scrollbar and make it visible only when it's necessary for example on hovering the div, I think something like this would do it:

```
.no-touch .scrollable {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.no-touch .scrollable:hover {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

or something like this depending on the screen size you want this to take effect

```
@media (max-width: 700px){
    .no-touch .scrollable {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .no-touch .scrollable:hover {
        overflow: auto;
    }
}
```

if this doesn't work, I think your solution for this is using some scrollbar plugin or create one

Comment: Nope, that's not what I asked. Look. If you open Chrome devtools, and turn on device emulation (phone icon next to Elements tab). Then select any device and refresh page to apply changes. Now you may notice, that scrollbar is still visible, even when you didn't scroll its content, unlike to the scrollbar of the whole page, that appears when you scroll content and disappear if you stop.

Comment: I don't know if it is only Chrome emulator behavior, that scrollbar of my `.scrollable` div is not hiding automatically, or is it something wrong with my `.no-touch .scrollable` rules. I guess, I have to borrow from someone some mobile device and check the code on actual device to find it out.